# Big decimal with generic class

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, bigdecimal

incompatible bounds compilation error

```java
public class Complex<T extends  BigDecimal, R extends BigDecimal> {

    private T r;
    private R i;    
    
    public Complex(T r, R i) {
        this.r = r;
        this.i = i;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Complex{" + "r=" + r + ", i=" + i + '}';
    }
    
    public T getR() {
        return r;
    }
    
    public R getI() {
        return i;
    }
    
    public Complex<T,R> add (Complex<T,R> other){
        return new Complex<T,R>((T) (r.add(other.r)), (R) (i.add(other.i)));
    }
}
```

And then when calling the class constructor:

```java
Complex<BigDecimal,BigDecimal> s = new Complex<>(12121,12121);
```

This compilation error occurs:

```
cannot infer type arguments for Complex<>
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    upper bounds: BigDecimal
    lower bounds: Integer
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends BigDecimal declared in class Complex
```

Comment: You’re passing integers where `T extends BigDecimal` is required. Why you need two separate types for real and imaginary is a mystery. Complex numbers don’t work like that.

Comment: The casting in `add()` is unsafe. Why would `r.add()` return `T` unless they're both `BigDecimal`? And if you know it's not a subclass, why use generics at all?

Comment: `12121` does not represent a `BigDecimal`. See also [How to pass a BigDecimal to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47477685/12567365)

Comment: And what you’re expecting to extend `BigDecimal` is a further mystery. Do you have subclasses of it? You could usefully lose the generics here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java won't convert an `int` to a `BigDecimal` implicitly, you need to explicitly provide a `BigDecimal` type to the constructor arguments.

```java
Complex<BigDecimal,BigDecimal> s = new Complex<>(
    BigDecimal.valueOf(12121), 
    BigDecimal.valueOf(12121)
);
```